Uanble to run production mode - NuxtJS
I cannot run production mode on NuxtJS.
I have
NODE_ENV=production

set in my .env
and below is my script inside the package.json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxi build --env production",
    "dev": "nuxi dev --env production",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
    "start-prod": "nuxi build && cross-env PORT=8001 node .output/server/index.mjs",
    "start-pm2": "nuxi build && pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production",
    "stop-pm2": "pm2 stop ecosystem.config.js --env production"
  }

I use the

npm run dev

to run the NuxtJs project. But it always stay in the development mode.
I do console.log inside the browser's console, it shows me

please help.

Using Vite ? Try to build and preview the app rather.

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/env#production-preview
